# no error message displayed for struts-jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, struts2

I am using struts-jquery plugin 3.1.0 with struts v2.2.3. i have a date picker in a jsp

```
    <td><sj:datepicker id="candidate.personalDetails.dateOfBirthItem"
        name="candidate.personalDetails.dateOfBirthItem" changeYear="true"
        yearRange="-100:-18" maxDate="-18" changeMonth="true" readonly="true" required="true"/><span style="color: #B7B7B7">mm/dd/yyyy</span>
    </td>
```

which i am trying to validate. i have a following entry in the validation xml

```
<field name="candidate.personalDetails.dateOfBirthItem">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message key="required.candidate.dateOfBirthItem"></message>
    </field-validator>
```

if submit page without providing value for the "candidate.personalDetails.dateOfBirthItem" no error message getting displayed, only form gets forwarded to entry specified in for "input" in the struts.xml. Validations messages for other non jquery fields are coming correctly. am i missing something?

Comment: Try to print the field error for the field "candidate.personalDetails.dateOfBirthItem" in any part of your input page and check if that helps you to see the error. See the fielderror tag reference - http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/fielderror.html

Comment: Thanks James, now i could see the see error message. For now this solves my problem. But in feature is the good practice of explicit handling error message for jquery components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use

```
<field-validator type="required">
```

instead of

```
<field-validator type="requiredstring">
```